# Code-Snippet not refreshed in Visual-Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I am creating Code Snippet in Visual-Studio 2010 using "Snippet Editor". All is working fine when i first save the snippet in the folder `... Visual Studio 2010\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets`.
The snippet is executed when i do CTRL-K CTRL-X and choose it in the list, and also by intellissence using the snippet Shortcut.

My problem comes when i only change the code of the snippet and save it again :

- the new code is executed when i hit CTRL-K CTRL-X
- the old code is executed when using intellisense ??
- the problem is still here when i reopen VS

I don't think this is a "Snippet Editor" issue. Is there any "Intelissence Cache" i would have to reset ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Visual Studio 2010, no more problem on the next version of VS

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in visual studio 2019.
I have a custom ( My Code ) snippet file with multiple CodeSnippet elements added with the Code Snippets Manager and recognized and working in visual studio.

I make two changes.
The first I add a comment to an existing CodeSnippet just to demo that the change has been recognized.
I then change the Shortcut element of another CodeSnippet and completely change the Code.

Import again with Code Snippets Manager and Overwrite.
Use both snippets.
The first now has the additional comment.
**The second does not have the code that is in the CDATA of the Code element but has what was there before !**

Put the two CodeSnippet elements in separate snippet files and all ok.

Comment: So no solution if I want to change the built-in "for" snippet for example?
I've noticed changing the shortcut does refresh IntelliSense autocompletion snippet insertion but I would like to keep with the "for" shortcut.

If you want to know why I'd like to modify this built-in snippet it's for replacing the "int" by a "var", in C# it's recommended practice.